# Using IPAD's as controllers for a Unity game

Tags: unity, multiplayer

We are making a Multiplayer game using Unity. The actual game would be run from a PC projected on a screen and the players would be using their respective Ipad as a controller to play the game. I am not sure how difficult this would be to achieve inside Unity but I am assuming that all the game data inside Unity would need to be fed and retrieved from some kind of a server. How would this be possible with Unity because each Ipad would have a separate Unity build and also a separate build for the PC from where the actual game would be running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Unity can publish games to iOS, this would be just like making any other client server application. The easiest would be to have the iPads all connected to the same network as the host PC, but you could easily utilize the Master Server tools provided with Unity to get everyone connected.

You'd likely use RPCs for most of your communications. As long as the PC build and iOS build defined the same RPCs (which they would if you don't change your code between builds), you wouldn't have a problem with them communicating.

As for how much game data you transfer between the clients and server, it will depend almost entirely on your game and how you've designed it.

Comment: As a side note, I think you'll have a hard time using iPads as controllers if the player is supposed to be looking at the projected screen. A touch screen does not make a very good controller, unless the controls are very simple.

Comment: Well, assuming the control scheme involves buttons on the touchscreen. I once imagined using iPads as steering wheels for a driving game on PC.

Comment: True, using the accelerometers would make for an easy control scheme.

Comment: thanks a lot. Yes using Ipads as controller is not intuitive but this is just a backup plan for us in case our original idea doesn't work. Also our design is very simple in terms of gameplay which is why we think Ipad would be ideal.